# Issue converting text from first person to second person, while ignoring text within quotations " "

Tags: python, python-3.x, nltk, google-colaboratory

I am trying to convert stories/sentences/words/etc from first person to second person grammer, but trying to not convert text within quotes " " or ' '.

This is being run in google colab, python 3 notebook. Code reads a file in my googledrive, reads the .txt file, converts the words from file through 'forms =' from first person to second person. There is also an issue where spaces are inserted before and after quotes (" and ' are affected) after conversion takes place.

```
import nltk
from google.colab import drive

drive.mount('/content/drive')

sent = open('/content/drive/My Drive/storyuno.txt', 'r') 


forms = {"am" : "are", "are" : "am", 'i' : 'you', 'my' : 'yours', 'me' : 'you', 'mine' : 'yours', 'you' : 'I', 'your' : 'my', 'yours' : 'mine'} # More?
def translate(word):
  if word.lower() in forms: return forms[word.lower()]
  return word

translated = []
quote_mode = False
for word in nltk.wordpunct_tokenize(sent.read()):
   if quote_mode:
       translated.append(word)
       if word == '"': quote_mode = False;

   if not quote_mode:
       translated.append(translate(word))
   if word == '"': quote_mode = True;

result = ' '.join(translated)

print(result) 
sent.close()
```

The story I input:

> The bottom line is that if I was going to tell anyone about the frog,
>   it would be Soy. I decided that our walk home would be the most
>   opportune time. “Did you see anything outside today during math?” I
>   asked Soy as we started walking. “What do you mean? Like in the sky?”
>   he asked, jumping over cracks in the sidewalk. “I mean right outside
>   the window. Like right up against it,” I answered. “Like a person?” he
>   asked, still hopping. Soy sat in the row farthest from the window, so
>   it was possible, but unlikely, for someone to walk by without him
>   noticing.

It converts to:

> The bottom line is that if you was going to tell anyone about the frog
>   , it would be Soy . you decided that our walk home would be the most
>   opportune time . “ Did I see anything outside today during math ?” you
>   asked Soy as we started walking . “ What do I mean ? Like in the sky
>   ?” he asked , jumping over cracks in the sidewalk . “ you mean right
>   outside the window . Like right up against it ,” you answered . “ Like
>   a person ?” he asked , still hopping . Soy sat in the row farthest
>   from the window , so it was possible , but unlikely , for someone to
>   walk by without him noticing .

The issue is that the text within quotes should NOT be converted.
Ex: I tell her, "You are boring". ---> You tell her, "You are boring".

Ignore any grammer mistakes besides the quote issue, I will fix it later.

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems with the quote. The first one is that `“` is not equal to `"`. The second is that quotes can be bundled up with neighbouring punctuation, so you get tokens like `?”`. The solution is to use a regular expression to check for the presence of any quotation in the token:

```
import re
quote_re = re.compile(r'["“”]')
```

then change

```
if word == '"':
```

into

```
if quote_re.search(word):
```

The issue with spaces can be fixed by detokenisation:

```
from nltk.tokenize.treebank import TreebankWordDetokenizer
detokenizer = TreebankWordDetokenizer()
result = detokenizer.detokenize(translated)
```

Comment: For some reason it is adding extra quotations now, the conversions work though. This is how it is currently converting: The bottom line is that if you was going to tell anyone about the frog, it would be Soy . you decided that our walk home would be the most opportune time . “ Did you see anything outside today during math?”?” I asked Soy as we started walking . “ “ What do you mean? Like in the sky?”?” he asked, jumping over cracks in the sidewalk . “